# Why does awk not fully match my range condition even when the data exists?

Tags: awk

On Linux, I am using `awk` with a `>= A && <= Z` conditional to match a range of lines within a file, but the returned lines are missing the "Z" data that I know exists.

**Is my command incorrect?**
**If not, how should I adjust my syntax without making the condition seem logically incorrect?**

The command `awk '$3 >= "[30/Aug/2023:08:03" && $3 <= "[30/Aug/2023:08:05"' /my/file` matches the range of timestamps in a file with contents like the following:

```
$ cat /my/file
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:02:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:03:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:04:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:05:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:06:01] Some sample log
```

However, the output is the following, which does not fully match my expected condition (the line containing "[30/Aug/2023:08:05" is missing):

```
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:03:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:04:01] Some sample log
```

I know I could just do `$3 <= "[30/Aug/2023:08:06"` to get the data I want, but anyone reading the code would be understandably confused.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to compare this kind of date format alphabetically?

Comment: @Fravadona Unfortunately, the format of the file contents is beyond my control, so I cannot use a more parse-able timestamp. However, Ed Morton's answer below seems to offer a way to deal with the issue you bring up.

Comment: The bigger problem here is that your dates are in `DD/Mon/YYYY` format which cannot be lexicographically compared without being first transformed in to something like `YYYYMMDD` with a numeric, zero-padded month and day. If you don't solve this problem first, you're wasting your time.

Comment: @Kaz I understand your point and agree with it fully. However, as I mentioned above, the format is completely beyond my control. These logs are generated by a third party which can/will not customize the format. In this particular use case, I don't have the luxury of accessing the entire file to perform some other pre-processing on all of the data -- the awk command is my only "window" into obtaining the log lines I need.

Comment: @Minute-Slice8546 Of course not. Getting the world to change inputs for you is a rare luxury.   When I say "... without being first transformed ...", I'm not necessarily talking about doing an additional pass through all the data. You may have to rearrange the date items that you are comparing as you compare them.

Answer (score 3):

**Awk compares the whole strings.** `[30/Aug/2023:08:06:01]` is greater than `[30/Aug/2023:08:06` just like `AB` is greater than `A`. It is not equal (and obviously not less), so `<=` is false.

If you compare only the part to (and including) the minutes field, `substr($3,1,18)<="[30/Aug/2023:08:06"` it is true. Or you can 'pad' with the maximum seconds: `$3<="[30/Aug/2023:08:06:59"`. (Depending on what program is writing this data, it *might* occasionally include a leap second, in which case you currently should use `:60` for the seconds field. However, the only people who really want leap seconds are astronomers and they recently got overruled, so this will go away in about a decade, and in several millennia noon will no longer occur at mid-day or midnight at mid-night, which will probably be confusing for the people alive then, if any.)

Alternatively, using the 'half-open' range `$3 >= firsttoinclude && $3 < firsttoexclude` (< not <=) is common in mathematics and many programming languages and I for one consider it intuitive, but people vary and you decide for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare dates for `>` or `<` that contain an alphabetic month abbreviation because, for example, you want dates in January to be less than dates in August but `J` is alphabetically greater than `A`. Instead you need to first create some kind of timestamp that can be compared, e.g. in numeric in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format as I use below, and then use that.

You're also trying to test for times being less than or equal to `08:05` (equivalent to `08:05:00`) when it sounds like you actually want to test for them being less than or equal to `08:05:59`.

Try this, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function toTs(dtStr,      mthNr,a) {
    gsub(/[][]/,"",dtStr)
    split(dtStr,a,"[/:]")
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2]) + 2) / 3
    return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",a[3],mthNr,a[1],a[4],a[5],a[6])
}

BEGIN {
    begTs = toTs(beg)
    endTs = toTs(end)
}
{ curTs = toTs($3) }
(begTs <= curTs) && (curTs <= endTs)
```

```
$ awk -v beg='30/Aug/2023:08:03:00' -v end='30/Aug/2023:08:05:59' -f tst.awk file
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:03:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:04:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:05:01] Some sample log
```

or if you always just want to discard the seconds and use a timestamp format of `YYYYMMDDHHMM`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function toTs(dtStr,    mthNr,a) {
    gsub(/[][]/,"",dtStr)
    split(dtStr,a,"[/:]")
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2]) + 2) / 3
    return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d",a[3],mthNr,a[1],a[4],a[5])
}

BEGIN {
    begTs = toTs(beg)
    endTs = toTs(end)
}
{ curTs = toTs($3) }
(begTs <= curTs) && (curTs <= endTs)
```

```
$ awk -v beg='30/Aug/2023:08:03' -v end='30/Aug/2023:08:05' -f tst.awk file
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:03:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:04:01] Some sample log
field1 field2 [30/Aug/2023:08:05:01] Some sample log
```