# Bash (awk, sort, etc.) pipeline to get SHA component of row with the most recent date string component

Tags: awk

Given the following text from a `wget` response:

```
<pre>Name                                      Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="06c3a7dfecf9bad1660eef8847d980588405fb4a/">06c3a7dfecf9bad1660eef8847d980588405fb4a/</a>  29-Aug-2023 19:05    -
<a href="06c3d541e12e7376f0a5ee6327a826322d99bdc6/">06c3d541e12e7376f0a5ee6327a826322d99bdc6/</a>  06-Jan-2023 20:05    -
<a href="08ba0368e7ed9180ed15e8ecfc6b0f4643f357e7/">08ba0368e7ed9180ed15e8ecfc6b0f4643f357e7/</a>  12-Apr-2022 21:19    -
<a href="0946584ccc7d322deaa71278d3a1965da955df4b/">0946584ccc7d322deaa71278d3a1965da955df4b/</a>  16-Mar-2023 20:48    -
<a href="0989b0548496273bf0f761dc35586acbce14dce8/">0989b0548496273bf0f761dc35586acbce14dce8/</a>  18-Jan-2023 19:47    -
<a href="96d96b8e151a60c47a7d2670ac977cddb7d3abe5">96d96b8e151a60c47a7d2670ac977cddb7d3abe5</a>    30-Aug-2023 07:17  -
<a href="0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4/">0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4/</a>  30-Aug-2023 17:08    -
<a href="0a98f6468de4ab414212afe423afedb65b4de530/">0a98f6468de4ab414212afe423afedb65b4de530/</a>  10-Nov-2022 13:44    -
<a href="96d96b8e151a60c47a7d2670ac977cddb7d3abe5">96d96b8e151a60c47a7d2670ac977cddb7d3abe5</a>    23-Aug-2023 21:52  -
</pre>
```

I'd expect to get `0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4`.

**What I've tried so far:**

I can isolate the date column with `awk '{print $3}'` but I want to filter it for the rows matching the `DD-MON-YYYY` pattern...

I think this is close to the proper regex but doesn't seem to work:

`awk '$3 ~ /([:digit:]{2}-)([:alpha:]{3}-)[:digit:]{4}/ {print $3, $4}'`

Assuming I can properly isolate the dates I'd want to then sort them and get the most recent one:

`sort -t '-' -k3n -k2M -k1n | tail -n1`

And then somehow get the SHA for that corresponding row...it seems the best way would be save the response to file and pipe it into a grep for the above encapsulated and pipe that into `awk` or `cut` to isolate the SHA.

Any suggestions for an elegant one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing OP's regex and appending OP's code snippets with a couple more bits into one gnarly one-liner:

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}/ {split($2,a,"[<>]"); sub(/[/]/,"",a[2]); print $3, $4 "-" a[2]}' wget.out | sort -t '-' -k3n -k2M -k1n  | tail -1 | cut -d'-' -f4
0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4
```

---

Doing everything in `awk`:

```
$ cat wget.awk

function toTs(dtStr,      mthNr,a) {
    split(dtStr,a,"[-]")
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2]) + 2) / 3
    return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",a[3],mthNr,a[1])
}

BEGIN      { regex = "[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}" }

$3 ~ regex { sub(/:/,"",$4)                     # strip ":" from HH:MM
             newTs = toTs($3) $4                # convert date/time to YYYYMMDDHHMM
             if (newTs > maxTs) {
                maxTs = newTs
                split($2,a,"[<>]")              # split 2nd field on ">" and "<"
                sub(/[/]/,"",a[2])              # strip off trailing "/"
                sha = a[2]                      # save as new (max) sha
             }
           }
END        { if (maxTs > 0) print sha }
```

**NOTES:**

- guts of the `toTs()` function borrowed from one of [Ed Morton's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77007173)
- this single `awk` script replaces all of OP's current code (`awk | sort | tail`) while adding the additional logic to extract the SHA corresponding to the most recent date/time

Running the `awk` script:

```
$ awk -f wget.awk wget.out                      # OP's (elegant?) one-liner
0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4
```

Answer (score 1):

With gawk, using a regex for the field-separator FS and concentrating on what separates the data you want, instead of the data itself, you can isolate the checksums with the following:

```bash
awk -F"<[^>]+>" '/^<pre/{next} {if (length($2)>=40) print substr($2,1,40)}' file
```

The field separator matching anything starting with `'<'` and not containing a `'>'` and terminated by a `'>'`. The check on `/^<pre/` is just used to skip those records.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file` that would result in:

```
$ awk -F"<[^>]+>" '/^<pre/{next} {if (length($2)>=40) print substr($2,1,40)}' file
06c3a7dfecf9bad1660eef8847d980588405fb4a
06c3d541e12e7376f0a5ee6327a826322d99bdc6
08ba0368e7ed9180ed15e8ecfc6b0f4643f357e7
0946584ccc7d322deaa71278d3a1965da955df4b
0989b0548496273bf0f761dc35586acbce14dce8
96d96b8e151a60c47a7d2670ac977cddb7d3abe5
0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4
0a98f6468de4ab414212afe423afedb65b4de530
96d96b8e151a60c47a7d2670ac977cddb7d3abe5
```

Now what you want to do with the sums is up to you. Let me know if I misunderstood your goal and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Very good catch. I fiddled with that a bit, but then went with the old standby `next`. I didn't put the combination of `!/^pre/ && length(..)` together.

Comment: A non-awk "Rube Goldberg" approach could be `html2text file | sed -e 's/^[^(]*(//' -e '/^[^0-9a-f]/d' -e 's/[/)].*$//' -e '/^$/d'` .. but I wouldn't recommend it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr extract.txr data.html
0a45a37b80557cf4252dbd916ec4ab8477f4b4e4
```

Code:

```
<pre>Name@nil
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
@(collect)
<a href="@hash">@hash</a> @dd-@mon-@year @hh:@mm @nil
@(rebind hash @(trim-right "/" hash))
@(bind mm @(pic "0#" (posqual mon '("" "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun"
                                    "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"))))
@(bind date `@year-@mm-@dd @hh:@mm`)
@(end)
@(do
   (put-line [hash (pos-max date)]))
```

Colorized by Vim:

[image: Colorized by Vim]